# Related forms in Symfony2 and The option "widget" does not exist

Tags: php, forms, symfony, widget, one-to-many

I has two entity Profile and Cars. Profile has many Cars. When I try to embed CarsFormType to ProfileFOrmType, I get this error:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Car, but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.
```

I have try to find solutions, but I didnt see any usefull results. I just want ot create one car when create the profile.

My model code:

Profile:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Car", mappedBy="profile", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $cars;
```

ProfileFormType:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('fio', null, array('label' => 'ФИО'));
    $builder->add('birthDate', null, array('label' => 'Дата рождения', 'widget' => 'single_text'));
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'Фото', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add('telephone', null, array('label' => 'Телефон'));
    $builder->add('contactMail', null, array('label' => 'Контактная почта'));
    /* $builder->add('category', 'choice', array(
        'label' => 'Категория прав',
        'choices' => array('B' => 'Категория B', 'C' => 'Категория C',),
        'expanded' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
    ));*/
        $builder->add('driverLicence', null, array('label' => 'Лицензия', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false));
        $builder->add('yearOnRoad', null, array('label' => 'Год за рулем', 'required' => false));
        $builder->add('cars', new CarType(), array('label' => 'Авто', 'required' => false));
//        $builder->add('cars', 'entity', array('label' => 'Авто', 'required' => false,      'class' => 'VputiUserBundle:Car'));
//        $builder->add('cars', 'collection', array('label' => 'Авто', 'required' =>     false, 'type' => new CarType()));
    $builder->add('submit', 'submit');
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'         => 'Vputi\UserBundle\Entity\Profile',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'profile_driver';
}
```

When in cars form type i raplece this :

```
 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
 {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Car',
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
 }
```

to this:

```
 public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => null,
        'cascade_validation' => true,
    ));
}
```

I get new error:

```
The option "widget" does not exist. Known options are: "action", "attr", "auto_initialize", "block_name", "by_reference", "cascade_validation", "compound", "constraints", "csrf_field_name", "csrf_message", "csrf_protection", "csrf_provider", "csrf_token_id", "csrf_token_manager", "data", "data_class", "disabled",
```

etc. Where is my problem ?

Comment: But have you read the rest of that error message? It clearly states, `You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Car.`

Comment: when i set data_class to null i get the error :
`The option "widget" does not exist.`

Comment: It's a different problem than what you've described.. You should either close this and make a new question, or edit the title to reflect the real problem. You should also include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only assume that the relationship between profile and car is a oneToMany meaning that in your form you would need to use a collection of `CarTypes` rather than a single one for your `cars` field. This means that when you form request the `cars` variable it is getting and `ArrayCollection` of `Car` object rather than a single `Car` that the form expects.

Change..

```
$builder->add('cars', new CarType(), array('label' => 'Авто', 'required' => false));
```

To..

```
$builder->add('cars', 'collection', array(
    'label'    => 'Авто',
    'required' => false,
    'type'     => new CarType(),
));
```

You can read up a little more on [embedding collections in the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and the actual options for the [collection type are here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

Comment: this way only add label, but not input fields

Comment: As it says in the "embedding collections in the docs" page you will need to initialize the object with a car or add the javascript so that you can add/remove cars.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is to have a [Collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

I think the properly way to setup this is to use this approach:

```
 $buider->add('cars', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new carType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        )
    );
```

You don't set the array with the form fields there. The fields you need in the auto need to go in carType. 
About the error: 
Symfony is expecting a Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Car Entity to match the corresponding type, and it's instead receiving another thing. That's why I'm trying to point you in the right direction.

Please take a look at this example of a [One to Many form example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496707/embed-a-collection-of-forms-doctrine-symfony/26502761#26502761) with their Entities here.

Just after hitting save I saw Qoop that is quite in the same direction of my answer :) So just ask if you cannot get it running.